# Regex non capturing group ignored?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
  <Field ID="{2B35B1DD-822A-47E2-9F8C-77006123FA45}"
       Name="NCPE_QualificationTitle"
       StaticName="NCPE_QualificationTitle"
       DisplayName="$Resources:Exigy.NCPE.ProfessionalDirectory.Structure,Fields_NCPE_QualificationTitle_DisplayName;"
       Description="$Resources:Exigy.NCPE.ProfessionalDirectory.Structure,Fields_NCPE_QualificationTitle_Description;"
       Group="$Resources:Exigy.NCPE.ProfessionalDirectory.Structure,NCPE_Group;"
       Type="Text"
    Required="FALSE" />
```

I'm trying to use this regex:

```
(?:\$Resources:.*,).*(?:;)
```

Which I thought should give me `Fields_NCPE_QualificationTitle_DisplayName` as it's the only part in a non capturing group. However it's matching this string:

`"$Resources:Exigy.NCPE.ProfessionalDirectory.Structure,Fields_NCPE_QualificationTitle_DisplayName;"`

What am I doing/understanding wrong?

Comment: It'd be nice to see the code you are using but are you sure you are getting the capture from the group (in fact you don't have any capturing groups I can see) and not the entire regex match? What you have quoted looks (at a glance) to be the text the regex matches. You can then examine the capturing groups in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to turn the first non-capturing group to positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`and the second one to positive lookahead `(?=...)`.

```
(?<=\$Resources:.*,).*(?=;)
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ppxqa2)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\$Resources:.*,).*(?=;)");
```

By default, it would print the `Groups[0]` ie, index 0 which contains all the matched characters.

Comment: yep, c# support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\$Resources:.*,)(.*)(?:;)
```

Try this and grab the capture or group 1 from it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/68

Your regex does not group any data so whole match is being returned.Once you introduce a group the you can access it by specifying group 1 or group 2